# LP in pulp - problem with decision variable

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I wish my decision variable to depend on the previous period’s starting variables which is changed by another decision variable. The line I get an error is:

```
my_problem += lineup_wk1[i] == starting_lineup[i] + trans_in[i] - trans_out[i] for i in players
```

where it says

```
  File "<ipython-input-21-42d75f1d2bc3>", line 4
    my_problem += lineup_wk1[i] == starting_lineup[i] + trans_in[i] - trans_out[i] for i in players
                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The full code is:

```
players = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
points = [4.2, 5.3, 6.0, 5.5, 4.5, 5.7, 4.8, 6.9]
cost = [4.5, 5.0, 5.1, 4.9, 5.2, 5.7, 5.2, 6.0]
starting_team = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]

player_points = dict(zip(players, points))
player_cost = dict(zip(players, cost))
starting_lineup = dict(zip(players, starting_team))

my_problem = pulp.LpProblem('LP_model', pulp.LpMaximize)
lineup_wk1 = pulp.LpVariable.dict('lineup_wk1_ % s', players, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=pulp.LpBinary)
trans_in  = pulp.LpVariable.dict('trans_in_ % s', players, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=pulp.LpBinary)
trans_out  = pulp.LpVariable.dict('trans_out_ % s', players, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=pulp.LpBinary)

my_problem += sum([player_points[i] * (lineup_wk1[i]) for i in players])

my_problem += sum([lineup_wk1[i] for i in players]) <= 4
my_problem += sum(trans_in[i] for i in players) <=2
my_problem += sum(trans_in[i] for i in players) == sum(trans_out[i] for i in players)
my_problem += lineup_wk1[i] == starting_lineup[i] + trans_in[i] - trans_out[i] for i in players

my_problem.solve()
```

Comment: What did you intend `for i in players` to mean?

Comment: Or rather, what did you intend the value on the right hand side of `my_problem +=` to be? A number? A list of numbers? A dictionary?

Comment: In any case, you have a problem where you are trying to use syntax that doesn't make sense, and the solution to that problem is to learn the basics of the programming language you're using first.

Comment: My intention is that the left of the constaint equals the right of the constraint so
lineup_wk1 = starting_lineup + trans_in - trans_out
as these are dictionaries with lists of numbers, I thought that the [i] represents the i row of the list and so saying for i in players mean do this for every row in the list.

Comment: @mkrieger1 the syntax is largely correct for `pulp`.  `pulp` overrides addition, so `my_problem += ...` is the correct way to add a legal expression to the model.  Whether we are in over our head here... we shall see!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the basic thing that is hanging you up is formulating a correct `pulp` expression for your constraint.  You are confusing summation / generator type of expressions when you want to make a constraint **for each** player.  So you are not summing or able to do `for i in players` in one line.  Instead, anytime your pulp model needs a "for each" constraint, you will need to make a loop (easiest way) and use the loop to make the full set of constraints.  In my example below, the loop will create 8 separate constraints, one for each player.

Note:  I'm not QA'ing the logic of your model, so if there is a math error, you'll need to dig.  You have a good framework here, but I would **strongly** suggest you rework the model to make this a simple knapsack problem (you already have the parts) to construct the best team possible of limited size and limited cost.  Those constraints are very straightforward.  If you can get that working, you can then start to venture out to this more creative in-out constraint.  :)

```
# pulp player & team

import pulp

players = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
points = [4.2, 5.3, 6.0, 5.5, 4.5, 5.7, 4.8, 6.9]
cost = [4.5, 5.0, 5.1, 4.9, 5.2, 5.7, 5.2, 6.0]
starting_team = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]

player_points = dict(zip(players, points))
player_cost = dict(zip(players, cost))
starting_lineup = dict(zip(players, starting_team))

my_problem = pulp.LpProblem('LP_model', pulp.LpMaximize)
lineup_wk1 = pulp.LpVariable.dict('lineup_wk1_ % s', players, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=pulp.LpBinary)
trans_in  = pulp.LpVariable.dict('trans_in_ % s', players, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=pulp.LpBinary)
trans_out  = pulp.LpVariable.dict('trans_out_ % s', players, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=pulp.LpBinary)

my_problem += sum([player_points[i] * (lineup_wk1[i]) for i in players])

my_problem += sum([lineup_wk1[i] for i in players]) <= 4
my_problem += sum(trans_in[i] for i in players) <=2
my_problem += sum(trans_in[i] for i in players) == sum(trans_out[i] for i in players)
# this will make a "for each player" constraint.  There is no summation... 
# note the change from i -> "player" which makes this more readable.
for player in players:  
   my_problem += lineup_wk1[player] == starting_lineup[player] + trans_in[player] - trans_out[player] 

my_problem.solve()
```

Comment: Many thanks for you input and using the For loop solves the problem. I do have a bigger piece of code that have many more constraints, but they work fine and this step confused me, hence I have produced a simple problem for demonstration (and easy to solve as a check).
I've never head of knapsack  before but a quick google seems it is something I will investigate a lot further. Many thanks for your input